# Which law of dot product should I know in order to understand this equivalence: $ \bf v.dv =$ $d$ $(\bf v.v)$?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, vectors, soft-question, vector-analysis

The context is an exercise in which it is asked to derive a well known formula regarding work :

$W=\int_{t1}^{t2} \bf F.d\bf r$ $= \frac{1}{2} mv_2^2 - \frac{1}{2} mv_1^2$

where $v_1$ and $v_2$ denote respectively initial and final velocity ( = $||\bf \vec v || \space)$.

The exercise key contains the following step that I cannot manage to understand, namely :

$m\int_{t1}^{t2} \bf v.$d$\bf v = $$m\int_{t1}^{t2} d \bf (v.v)$

Am I at least right in supposing that I have a problem in understanding the dot product transformation ? Does it rather consist in undersanding the integration process?

In which direction should I look for?

Source : Spiegel, *Outline Of Theoretical Mechanics*:

[image]

Comment: Consider that the derivative of a dot product between functions works like the normal derivative of a product of functions so $[v \cdot v]' =\frac{dv}{dt} \cdot v+     v \cdot \frac{dv}{dt} = 2 (v \cdot \frac{dv}{dt}) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I think this is playing a little too fast-and-loose with the notation, and I'm a physicist.  Starting from this point,
$$
m\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\cdot\vec{v}\,dt,
$$
note that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}) =
\vec{v}\cdot\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}+ \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\cdot\vec{v}
=
 2\vec{v}\cdot\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt},
$$
which is just the product rule.  To prove that the product rule works for dot products, you can write $\vec{v}$ in terms of its components $v_x(t)$, $v_y(t)$, and $v_z(t)$, and use the normal product rule on each term.

At that point, then, you can write
$$
m\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\cdot\vec{v}\,dt
=
m\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v})\,dt
$$
at which point you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus, and you're done.

---

Just to be complete, note that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v})
&=
\frac{d}{dt}(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)
=
2v_x\frac{dv_x}{dt}+2v_y\frac{dv_y}{dt}+2v_z\frac{dv_z}{dt}
=2\vec{v}\cdot\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and reader friendly  answer!